# Comparing Strings results in a wrong answer in lighting component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have a lightning component where I am trying to compare the user's profile Id and based on the result execute some logic but the result I get in the compare is wrong - although the IDs are the same I am getting false, no matter which type of compare I use.

In the below code I see on screen that the v.runningUser.ProfileId is **00e1o000001EImgAAG** but the compare results in false:

```
    testId-->{!v.runningUser.ProfileId}
    <br/>        
    rb --> {!v.runningUser.profileId == '00e1o000001EImgAAG'}
    <br/>
    wrd--> {!notequals(v.runningUser.profileId, '00e1o000001EImgAAG')}
    <br/>
    notequal --> {!not(v.runningUser.profileId == '00e1o000001EImgAAG')}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the expression you are testing

it should be `{!v.runningUser.ProfileId}` and not `{!v.runningUser.profileId}`

**Correct code:**

```
    testId-->{!v.runningUser.ProfileId}
    <br/>        
    rb --> {! equals(v.runningUser.ProfileId, '00e1o000001EImgAAG')}
    <br/>
    wrd--> {!notequals(v.runningUser.ProfileId, '00e1o000001EImgAAG')}
    <br/>
    notequal --> {!not(v.runningUser.ProfileId == '00e1o000001EImgAAG')}
```

Also check [expression functions reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm) for all the available function